# Spring LDAP Authentication UnknownHostException

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to do simple AD authentication using Spring LDAP. Below is my config xml

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
 <property name="url" value="ldap://ValidADhost:port" />
 <property name="base" value="dc=ad,dc=XXX,dc=com"/>
 <property name="userDn" value="ValidUserName" />
 <property name="password" value="ValidPassword" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>
```

Authentication code:

```
public boolean login(String username, String password) {
        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true); 
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", username));
        return ldapTemplate.authenticate("", filter.toString(), password);
}
```

With this code, Im getting the following Exception

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException:ValidADhost:port;nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException:ValidADhost:port[Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException:ValidADhost:port]

I am able to get the user details from the same LDAP hostname:port in C# test program.

I appreciate any help/pointers/solutions.

Comment: Are you able to telnet LDAP server at the specified port?

Comment: it seems that instead of the 'ValidADhost' the combination 'ValidADhost:port' is used to determine the IP-Address ... see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html.